# In Ruby, how best to return the non-nil value of a computationally expensive search?

Tags: ruby, select, null, find

I have a computationally expensive find, and for obvious reasons want the computed value rather than the original:

```
%x(...).each_line.find { |l| m = l.match(/^(\S+).*System(.*)/) ; break m if m }
```

It seems the `find` is necessary because giving the block to `each_line` returns the original string on failure.

If I want every matched line's group, I can `map { ... }.compact`, although I gather that's 'not the Ruby way' because I should `select` before I `map`. (Is that really considered the only acceptable practice?)

I tried using that approach with `each_line` turned lazy so I could ask for `first` at the end, but I couldn't `compact` it. Needing to write `select{|x|x}` underwhelms me.

```
%x(...)
  .each_line.lazy
  .map { |l| l.match(/^(\S+).*System(.*)/) }
  .select { |x| x }  # lol, .compact pls.
  .first
```

Is there something more elegant?

---

Update: I'm going with

```
"foo\nbar".each_line.lazy.flat_map{ |l| l.match(/([ao])/) || [] }.first
```

but an honourable mention goes to Simple Lime for the `grep` based answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) to do what you want, I think:

```
matches = %x(./script.rb).each_line.lazy.grep(/^(\S+).*System(.*)/) do
  Regexp.last_match
end
```

`grep` will

> Returns an array of every element in enum for which Pattern === element. If the optional block is supplied, each matching element is passed to it, and the block’s result is stored in the output array.

so by passing the block, we're essentially `map`/`collect` ing the output of [`Regexp.last_match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match) only for the lines that matched. And `Regexp.last_match`

> returns the MatchData object generated by the last successful pattern match.

Comment: Thanks: although `Regexp.last_match` feels like a code smell, it's clearly part of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
str.each_line.find { |l| m = l.match(/^(\S+).*System(.*)/) ; break m if m }
```

Is the same as this:

```
str.each_line.find { |l| l.match(/^(\S+).*System(.*)/) }
```

If you want all matches back, you're building a new result. That means you probably want a `reduce`:

```
str.each_line.reduce([]) do |matches, line|
  if match_data = line.match(/^(\S+).*System(.*)/)
    matches << match_data
  end
  matches
end
```

One loop with an array result that contains only match data.

Comment: find without the 'break m if m' returns the line. I wanted the match.